# Userform combobox take first value only - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a user form set up which contains a ComboBox. The ComboBox is populated with values from a dynamic named range "List1" .. every thing is Fine .. when I choose the first value from the list it works and I could complete my tasks .. but when I choose another value from the list the value disappears and the combobox value become empty ..
here is the code :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.RowSource = "'[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]DATA'!List1"
ComboBox1.DropDown
Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Could anyone give me a solution please ..

UPDATE:
I follow the instructions in this tutorial .. but I do it in a userform:
http://trumpexcel.com/2013/10/excel-drop-down-list-with-search-suggestions

Comment: Usually you populate the Combobox from the Initialize event. Then perform some action in the change event. You don't repopulate the same combobox with the same list. Every time you change it.

Comment: Could there be something wrong with the formula for your dynamic name?

Comment: The problem is with the dynamic range formula.

Comment: =DATA!$D$4:INDEX(Table1[H3];MAX(Table1[H2]);1)

Comment: this is the formula .. please help me change it ..

Comment: I don't know what you want it to do, so I am unable to further assist.  I would recommend that you revise your question and describe what you expect that formula to return. Also you may want to look at the "Table1" Name object, as that may be contributing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem: the combobox will change its values by the selected item

select item 5 -> item 5 is selected (also if values change)
If the source is changed (no item 5 exists or has an empty string) the box will be empty. You are NOT selecting a value! Try it like that:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim ListCB As Variant, TmpText As String
  If Not IsArray(Sheets("Data").Range(Names("List1"))) Then
    temptext = Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value
    Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = ""
  End If
  ListCB = Sheets("Data").Range(Names("List1"))
  If Len(temptext) Then Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = temptext
  ComboBox1.List = ListCB
End Sub
```

`ListCB` will not change when an item is selected -> your combobox stays as it is.

**EDIT:**
Try it this way:

```
Dim ListCB As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim TmpText As String
  If Not IsArray(Sheets("Data").Range(Names("List1"))) Then
    temptext = Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value
    Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = ""
  End If
  ListCB = Sheets("Data").Range(Names("List1"))
  If Len(temptext) Then Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = temptext
  GetCBList
End Sub

Sub GetCBList()
  Dim b As Variant, i As Long
  Dim a() As Variant: ReDim a(UBound(ListCB))
  For Each b In ListCB
    If Len(b) Then
      If InStr(1, b, ComboBox1.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or ComboBox1.Value = "" Then: a(i) = b: i = i + 1
    End If
  Next
  If i > 0 Then ReDim Preserve a(i - 1)
  ComboBox1.List = a
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  GetCBList
  ComboBox1.DropDown
  Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Attention: `Dim ListCB As Variant` needs to be outside of the subs/functions (should be first line at all in this form). Replace `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` and `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` with this code and check if that is what you want.

Comment: I try to run this solution but a message with error 1004 show "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: tried it again -> download from your link -> copy my code -> replace the `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`-part of your userform -> works without any errors...

Comment: I want the combobox list values changed as I typed .. as in this tutorial : http://trumpexcel.com/2013/10/excel-drop-down-list-with-search- suggestions .. could you please help to make it work with userform? .. everything is ready in the file attached ..

Comment: you may simply put after `Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = ComboBox1.Value` the line `ComboBox1.Value = Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value`... the combobox itself will not be empty (but the list will be)... however, make sure youre not ending in an endless loop... i'll look into it...

Comment: @Abeer i edited my answer... pls check if that fits your needs (you may replace `ListCB = Sheets("Data").Range(Names("List1"))` with the full range or or even a bigger range... empty cells will be ignored and there is no need for your `List1` to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much .. it works now .. I very appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to display blank in cell A3 - it all worked, except I had to type in the combo box to get the values to appear (i.e. get the change event to fire).  Also try changing `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` (the book with the code in).

Try populating your combo box when you first open the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.RowSource = "'[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]DATA'!List1"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work .. still when I choose another value than the first from list the combobox become empty!

Comment: @Abeer I have tested this solution and it works as-expected.